# Find a smooth rapidly decreasing function that is not Schwartz.

Tags: real-analysis

A rapidly decreasing function is a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^d:\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $|x|^n f(x)$ is bounded for every non-negative integer $n$. A Schwartz function is a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{C}$ such that all derivatives $\partial_{x_1}^{n_1}\cdots \partial_{x_d}^{n_d}f$ are rapidly decreasing.

I need to find a function that is smooth rapidly decreasing but  not Schwartz,  I can only think of the exponential function $e^{-|x|^2}$ which is Schwartz.

Comment: $f(x) = \cos(e^{x^4}) e^{-x^2}$ or something like that

Comment: @user1952009 It seems a good suggestion, thanks. If we also require that all derivatives of $f$ are bounded, then $f$ is Schwartz, but I don't know how to prove this.

Comment: each derivative is bounded when $|x| \to \infty$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 If the dimension $d=1$, then $f$ is analytic, I'm not sure about the higher dimensions.

Comment: It seems that smoothness is the easiest thing to break.  Take your favourite Schwartz function and set it equal to $0$ on the points with integer coordinates?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the function
$$f(x)=e^{-x}\sin(e^{x})$$
should work well because this is definitely rapidly decreasing, but its first derivative is
$$f'(x)=-e^{-x}\sin(e^{x})+\cos(e^{x})$$
which is not decreasing to $0$ as $x\to\infty$ at all.