# Give an example to show that not all smooth rapidly decreasing functions are Schwartz fiunctions.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Give an example to show that not all smooth rapidly decreasing functions are Schwartz functions.

hint is provided: Try to come up with a function

$$f(x)=\sum_k\frac 1 {2^k} f_k(x) \text{ where each of }  f_k\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$$

i am wondering what kind of $f_k$ can i take here? any suggestion

Comment: A solution not using the same method: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675183/find-a-smooth-rapidly-decreasing-function-that-is-not-schwartz

Answer (score 1):

You could let each $f_k$ be a "bump" function: a nonnegative smooth function that vanishes off a ball.

One way to go about this is to start with a function $g$ that satisfies the following:

- $g \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$,
- $0 \le g(x) \le 1$,
- $|x| \ge 1$ implies $g(x) = 0$,
- $g(0) = 1$.

There are specific examples of such functions, but we can take the existence of such a $g$ for granted.

Now let $f_k(x) = f(2^k(x-k))$. You should be able to verify that $f$ defined as in the question is rapidly decreasing. The graph of $f$ consists of a bunch of nonoverlapping bumps whose heights decrease to $0$. On the other hand, $f'(x) \not\to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ because of the cancellation of the $2^k$'s.